# CSOM ListCollectionItems count based on folder path performance issues

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, mvc

I have a design requirement to get total count for ListItemCollection based on Files specified by Folder Path. I currently have the following code in place:

```
using (ClientContext spClientContext = AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, _clientId, _clientSecret))
{
    if (spClientContext != null)
    {
        int totalCount = 0;
        
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();

        camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = getSiteUrlAbsolutePath(siteUrl) +
            "/Shared Documents/" + folderPath;

        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope="RecursiveAll">" +
                                "<Query>" +
                                    "<Where>" +
                                        "<Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value></Eq>" +
                                    "</Where>" +
                                "</Query>" +
                            "</View>";
                            
        // ************ Start Execution Time Logging ***************************************************************                            
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();             

        List list = spClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

        ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);

        spClientContext.Load(listItems);

        spClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        totalCount = listItems != null && listItems.Count > 0 ? listItems.Count : 0;
    
        // ************ Stop Execution Time Logging ***************************************************************     
        stopwatch.Stop();
        
        Debug.WriteLine("Execution time: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms.");       

    }
}
```

Execution time for 5 runs:

```
Execution time: 1348 ms. Total Count = 403
Execution time: 1125 ms. Total Count = 403
Execution time: 1447 ms. Total Count = 403
Execution time: 1102 ms. Total Count = 403
Execution time: 1402 ms. Total Count = 403
```

This seems exceptionally long for a simple query? Are there any obvious ways I can optimize the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need all the fields? You could use `clientContext.Load(items, includes => includes.Include(i => i.ID))` instead of loading all of the fields. Just my understanding of what it's doing, you probably could only use the ID of the file/folder itself, not all the fields, in order to count them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Including just the ListItem.Id did seem to improve performance. Being fairly new to the CSOM API is it correct to say if you do not specify specific properties (initialize) in the Load statement it loads all obj properties by default?